# Chris Banes Pull To Refresh ListView/GridView in Fragment

Tags: android, listview, fragment, pull-to-refresh

I am trying to include Chris Banes Pull to refresh implementation inside a Fragment and I am getting the following error at creating the PullToRefreshListView:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.R$id.pull_to_refresh_text
```

The point of PullToRefreshListView creation is at onCreateView in a class inheriting ListFragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    View lvOld = viewGroup.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    listView = new PullToRefreshListView(getActivity());
    listView.setId(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    listView.setDrawSelectorOnTop(false);
    adapter = new LazyAdapter(getActivity());
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    FrameLayout parent = (FrameLayout) lvOld.getParent();

    parent.removeView(lvOld);
    lvOld.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    parent.addView(listView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    return viewGroup;

}
```

The layout is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#FF0000">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same error after replacing of "pull to refresh" widget  http://markupartist.com [from Johan Nilsson](http://markupartist.com). It was necessary to delete header.xml from layout directory (containing references to the text mentioned in your error message). Texts are already part of the Chris Banes's library.

Comment: Thank you so much! It appears to be a problem that I had both libraries referenced and the layout name was the same. I delete the reference for Johan Nilsson´s library and now is working :)